# When updating a Google App Script Add On, does it updates for the user who already installed it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

Well, the thing is that I mistakenly published a Google Forms Add On with a manually-installed formSubmit trigger. It was a mistake because I pretended the code to be run by the user. So now I fixed the script and set the trigger to be programatically installed. But I keep getting an error (from one user) that says that the user doesn't have permission at the onSubmit function.

I suspect that, maybe, this user installed the Add On (and its manually installed trigger) prior to my update and now the error happens whenever that Form is submitted. Am I right? So I shouldn't worry, since this is something out of my reach. What would you do?

Thank you.

Comment: To prevent any propagation issue, could you please tell the user to uninstall and install the add-on again?

Comment: Thank you, that would be great, is there a way to communicate with the users?